# Confusion with closures and why incorrect values are being returned

Tags: javascript, closures

I thought I had a decent understand of closures and then my friend gave me a problem to solve involving closures (which I did not know at the time). Here is the block of code:

```
function fixMe() {
   var numbers = [];
   var i = 0;
   for (; i < 10; i++) {
     numbers[i] = function () {
        return i;
     };

   }
   return numbers;
}
```

So when I call:

```
var numbers = fixMe();
alert(numbers[2]());
```

It always alerts 10, even if I had `i` as a parameter in the `fixMe()` function.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/atshkaae/3/) is a jsfiddle of it.

The solution he told me ended up being:

```
function fixMe() {
    var numbers = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (; i < 10; i++) {
        numbers[i] = function (i) {
            return function () {
                return i;
            };
        }(i);
    }

    return numbers;
}

var numbers = fixMe();
alert(numbers[2]());
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c1v6n8f/) of the solution. I tried quite a few things but never came to the conclusion that I needed nested functions.

Currently, I don't understand why the first function will return me an array of functions that always returns 10. I assume this is the closure problem? Second, why does the same function inside another function solve the problem? It seems like the `(i)` at the end of the function creation for the solution is needed, but it doesn't even compile if you add it in without the nested function. What exactly is it doing? Is there another more simple solution?

This may be a lot of questions, but I feel they'd all help with my understanding of closures in javascript should they be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version (the broken one) creates a set of functions that all **share** the exact same variable `i`. That is, each function in the array retains access to that (single) variable `i`. It's not a *copy* of the value of `i`, it *is* `i`.

At the end of the loop, what's the value of that variable `i`?  It's `10`.  When you later call the functions, that's the value you get back.

Now, in the second version, the interposed function makes a copy of the value of `i` and stores it into a local (closure) variable that's freshly-created on each iteration. It's a distinct closure because each iteration has a distinct function call to the anonymous wrapper function. The function call (just like any other JavaScript function call) passes a copy of the value of the outer `i` into the anonymous function, and thereafter that copy will never be changed. Thus, each of the functions in the array now has a private `i`, so the former problem is thus solved.

Comment: Excellent, that does it explain it quite well. Just one more question, what exactly is the `(i)` doing at the end of the second function. When I remove it, it alerts the function itself.

Comment: @JeremyW that's the `()` operator, which causes a function to be invoked. Like, if you have a function, and you want to call it, you write the function name and then a parenthesized list of arguments: `Math.sqrt(5)`.  Same thing here: what's before that `(i)`? A function! Not a function *name*, but a complete function that's instantiated in-place. So that `(i)` causes that function to be invoked. Sometimes that overall construct is called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).